# How to apply mask to a default value in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11, using-directives, custom-directive

I have a mask-phone directive that works perfectly in the input when the user write a value, but I need to set a default value and I don't know how to apply the mask directive in the component method. The value is show it in the input without the mask and only if I modify that value the mask comes.

The problem I have is that in Germany has several possibilities for a telephone number, so I can not set a specific mask in the default value, for example:
(49)(170)-1111111
(49)(1514)-1111111
(49)(25679)-1111111

I wrote an example, that you can see in the follow link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-phone-mask-directive-roeqfk?file=app/app.component.ts

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide the default value from inside the directive and set the mask in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. This would additionally have the benefit that the default value is the same each time you use this directive.

Code:

```ts
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgControl} from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appPhoneMask]'
})
export class PhoneMaskDirective implements OnInit{
  defaultValue: string = '4912345678'

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl, private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.applyMask(this.defaultValue)
  }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event): void {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }
  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event): void {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }
  onInputChange(event, backspace): void {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    
    this.applyMask(newVal)
  }

  applyMask (value): void {
    if (value.length === 0) {
      value = '';
    } else if (value.length <= 3) {
      value = value.replace(/^(\d{0,2})/, '($1)');
    } else if (value.length <= 6) {
      value = value.replace(/^(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) ($2)');
    } else if (value.length <= 12) {
      value = value.replace(/^(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,7})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    } else if (value.length <= 13) {
      value = value.replace(/^(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,7})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    } else if (value.length <= 14) {
      value = value.replace(/^(\d{0,2})(\d{0,5})(\d{0,7})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    } else {
      value = value.substring(0, 14);
      value = value.replace(/^(\d{0,2})(\d{0,5})(\d{0,7})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(value);
  }

  /** This method allows to keep the formControl value without the mask, in order to use it in backend queries */
  @HostListener('input') onChange(): void {
    const newVal = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.ngControl.control.setValue(newVal, {
      emitEvent: false,
      emitModelToViewChange: false,
      emitViewToModelChange: false
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: In my project when I subscribe to the backend I receive a list of telephones, so I need to take the first telephone from that response, I though that it would be automaticly once that I set it to the input but it is not. I think that yes the Directive ngOnInit is the correct place to do so, but how can i send the telephone from the component to the directive.

Comment: You can do so by using the `@Input` decorator just like in any other child component. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: Thanks! I did it, still does not work, but it's because somehow the directive receive the value empty, so I muss check because in the html the value is showed, then I don't know where got lost.